# UITabBarItem Icons: Adding Animations in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I'm currently making an app with a UITabBar, and I would like the icons to be animate whenever an item is touched, is there any way to do this in Objective-C?

After going through some questions here in StackOverflow, I've noticed that I can't seem to find any code for Objective-C that can do this, is Swift the only way to do this?

Comment: you can use swift frame works in objective-c (OR) rewrite the swift frame work code in objective c

Comment: @job-mendoza: Animation APIs are provided by UIKit, CoreAnimation frameworks. Both objective-C and Swift uses same framework. Few of these APIs are changed to swift and few of them are still in Objective-C and swift simply calls it under the hood. So all am trying to say is if u can do some animation in Swift obviously that's possible in Objective-C as well :)

Comment: https://github.com/polobymulberry/animated-tab-bar-Objective-C

Comment: thank you for the information and links provided, I will look into these and do some more research. :)

Comment: @JobMendoza You can add this `Swift` library to your `Objective C` code : https://github.com/jithinpala/JBTabBarAnimation